# Nodejs - Async/Await to my controller

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, async-await

Right now i have this route controller

```
export let remove = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    Area.removeAndRecalc(req.query.ids).then(() => {
        return res.json({ success: true });
    });
};
```

and calls the following model method

```
areaSchema.statics.removeAndRecalc = async function(ids) {
    let parents = await this.model("Area").find({_id: ids});

    await this.model("Area").delete(
        {
            _id: ids
        }
    );
    await parents.forEach((parent) => {
        parent.recalcParentChilds();
    })
    return;
}
```

The function returns a promise. Is it possible to write this code inside the controller? I try to use "async" to my controller but i doesn't work

Something like this (doesn't work)

```
export let remove = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    let parents = await this.model("Area").find({_id: req.query.ids});

    await this.model("Area").delete(
        {
            _id: req.query.ids
        }
    );
    await parents.forEach((parent) => {
        parent.recalcParentChilds();
    })
    return res.json({ success: true });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear "what" exactly doesn't work. An exception or description of the bad behaviour would be useful.

But check out [async-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-middleware). I'm using it like this, for example in some projects:

```
import { wrap } from 'async-middleware'
//Loads of code, some of which creates router, an Express router.
router.get('/some/path/here', wrap(async (req, res) {
   var data = await dataFromService();
   res.write(renderData(data));
   res.end();
}));
//Loads of code
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a mistake with `forEach` in the `remove` function , `forEach` returns `undefined` not a promise so `await` won't work as expected, try to something like this :

```
 export let remove = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

    //...

    for (let i=0; i< parent.length;i++){ // <-- use for loop instead of forEach  
       await  parent.recalcParentChilds();
    }
    return res.json({ success: true });
};
```